# Google map in hidden div

Tags: google-maps, hidden

I am using one of those collapsing div to hide the google map in my webpage.
But when I trigger the event to expand the div and reveal the google map, it does not appear.
And this problem is only with IE, all other browsers work just fine.
I found this same question asked with the response to add this code:

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

But where am I supposed to place it? I placed in a Javascript function that gets called when the div collapses but it doesn't work. Am I supposed to replace "map" with the name of my map?
I got the code for the google map as a "iframe" tag from the google site and I just pasted it into
my webpage...
Please explain.

Comment: How are you actually triggering the events exactly? What code are you using to reveal the div? We need to see what your doing, so we can help you to get it right. Do you have a link to the test site?

Answer (score 1):

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

is for when you are using the Maps API. Thereby map is a reference to your map object.

But you are not using the API. You are using an iframe from Google Maps.

Google Maps doesn't like being in a div that is hidden. A solution I beleive is to make the iframe say 1x1 px. Then resize the div to make it big enough - and visible.

Alternative is to give the iframe a src="about:blank". and then after you show the div, dynamically set the src to the right url. This way the map is actully loaded while the div is visible. 
(this is probably better, as you not causing the user to load the iframe stuff, even if they dont open the map)

Answer (score 0):

Since in your question you say you are not using Google Maps API, you could do the following:

Wrap the map:

```
<div id="map-wrapper"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/..." /></div>
```

Use this code (jQuery version) when the map is shown:

```
$('#map-wrapper').html( $('#map-wrapper').html() );
```

Javascript version:

```
document.getElementById("map-wrapper").innerHTML = document.getElementById("map-wrapper").innerHTML;
```

When the map is shown the content of the wrapper (the Google map iframe) will be regenerated, therefore reloaded.